# Curl Error when installing Plex Media Server on RPI 3

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, media-server, raspbian-stretch

I followed a guide for installing Plex Media Server on Raspbian on YouTube. In the guide it was successful but when I tried to execute in on my own RPI 3 it didn't work. See the terminal output below:

```
....
Downloading readynas package ...
#                                                                          1.6%
##                                                                         3.2%cd 
curl: (56) SSL read: error:00000000:lib(0):func(0):reason(0), errno 104
Checksum mismatch. Downloaded file does not match this package.
dpkg: error processing package plexmediaserver-installer (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of plexmediaserver:
 plexmediaserver depends on plexmediaserver-installer; however:
  Package plexmediaserver-installer is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package plexmediaserver (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 plexmediaserver-installer
 plexmediaserver
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
....
```

This is my system information:

```
PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)"
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="9"
VERSION="9 (stretch)"
ID=raspbian
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianForums"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianBugs"
```

Comment: Have you tried to rerun the "execution"?

Comment: Yes, just now i re-run it couple of times.. until i successfully intalled it.. seems to be, i think, its on their side? the readynas download

Comment: error 104 indicate that its on their sidel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who encountered this, just re-run it until its successful, seem to be from what i experienced, its something about the peer being refused or something. Just look up `errno 104` on google. Yes, don't give up just re-run it. nothings wrong with your pis